# Weinberg QFT Vol 1, charge renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, charge, renormalization, protons

Weinberg says (Chapter 10, section 10.4) that we have to assume that the bare charge, $q_{Bl}$ that appears in the Lagrangian is equal and opposite for the electron and for the particles (two $u$-quarks and one $d$ quarks) that make up proton. I don't quite understand the statement. I understand that the charge renormalization is a consequence of field $A_\mu$ renormalization. i.e. $q_{Bl}A_{B\mu}$ after field renormalization becomes $\sqrt{Z}q_{Bl}A_{\mu}$, and the physical charge is defined as $\sqrt{Z}q_{Bl}$. Therefore, the scaling is actually independent of the single-particle state, free or bound; therefore positron has the same renormalized or physical charge as proton. But Weinberg's statement seems to suggest that in Lagrangian we have to assume equal and opposite charges for electron and quarks? Am I just reading the sentence wrong?

Comment: Page might be different in different editions, mine's at 445. But this is in chapter 10, section 10.2, right after equation 10.4.18 for charge renormalization.

Comment: He probably refers to the fact that we have to put the charge matrix $Q=diag(2/3,-1/3)$ by hand in the theory before renormalization is performed

Comment: Yes, it seems OP is just reading the sentence wrong. Weinberg did not mean to suggest that quarks and electrons have opposite charges, only that protons and electrons have.

Comment: Yes, I agree I think the sentence is worded weirdly. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we said is wrong:

When we rewrite the term
$$
q_B \overline{\psi}^B A^B_\mu \gamma^\mu \psi^B 
= Z_1 q_R \overline{\psi}^R A^R_\mu \gamma^\mu \psi^R
$$
where $A_B = \sqrt{Z_3}A_R$ and $A_R$ is called the renormalized field, $\psi^B = \sqrt{Z_2} \psi^R$, and
$$
q_R = \frac{Z_2\sqrt{Z_3}}{Z_1} q_B
$$
Now, the $q_R$ is called the ‘renormalized charge’ instead of the ‘physical charge’. Whether it equals the physical charge depends on the renormalization scheme, for example if you use OS (on-shell) scheme then they are equal, by definition.

For your question, I think Weinberg aims to say that we should assume in the Lagrangian that the bare charge has a ration of
$$q^B_{e} : q^B_{up}: q^B_{down} = 1:\frac{2}{3}:-\frac{1}{3}$$
But this statement is for bare charge.

But for the situation of renormalized/physical charge, whether they hold this ratio after renormalization, is out of my knowledge. I’ll be grateful if you can explain to me that part.